# UITextField Crashes when editing twice

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

My app crashes when editing the UITextFields. Specifically, it seems to happen if I edit the same one twice?

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    //Breakpoint crash at this line:
    if (textField.text.isEmpty) {
        // no text entered
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error which shows up?

Comment: It's very vague. Just Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT.

Comment: It has something to do with your other code. This code shouldn't crash. Have you set the delegate of your textfield?

Comment: Yes. I am creating 3 textFields in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. In this method, I set the delegate with `textView.delegate = self`

Comment: textView? But you are using an UITextField in that example. That way you need an UITextViewDelegate

Comment: Sorry, I named it textView by accident, but I am definitely using the UITextField delegate. Also, it only crashes when I have text in all three of the textFields.

Comment: This will crash if `textField.text` is `nil`. Is there a change that you set it to `nil` somewhere?

Comment: This sounds right, but I am not intentionally setting it to nil anywhere. Is there any way it could become nil?

Comment: Also, I am setting the textField up in code, not the IB.